# php retrieve session data from one or more sessions

Tags: php, session

I've looked for an answer to this but can't find it. Please point me in the right direction if this question is already answered but I'm just wording it different.

I have a registration page that sets a session when a new user registers. Then, there's a login page for when the user comes back and logs in. The login page sets a different session.

How do I check if either of the sessions are set?

This is what I'm trying:

```
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['Register'])or empty($_SESSION['Login'])){
  header("location:../notLoggedIn.php");
}
```

Comment: first of all what is the need of session at the time of registration (no mean).2.`if (empty($_SESSION['Register']) && empty($_SESSION['Login'])){`

Comment: I start a session so I can store the user_id from the database and then use it to allow the user to edit their profile (update their row in the db)

Comment: what you have to that on registration no need to do anything related session. on login page you have to check user exist or not with the given credentials and if yes then add some data to the session and redirect to profile page. on each page start session and check that data exist or not? if yes ok, otherwise send him to login page again

Comment: How do I know which user it is when they register and they want to edit their profile page?

Comment: Man after registration when user go with login, he will provide you username and password based on that you have to store his user_id in session and based on that detail show his data on profile page at the time of saving the edited data use that session id to save data into correct columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not used `empty()` before but I have always used the code below:

```
// Your original solution
if (!isset($_SESSION['Register']) || !isset($_SESSION['Login'])){
    header("location:../notLoggedIn.php");
}
// using AND instead of OR
if (!isset($_SESSION['Register']) && !isset($_SESSION['Login'])){
    header("location:../notLoggedIn.php");
}
// Nesting the IF
if(!isset($_SESSION['Register'])){
    if(!isset($_SESSION['Login'])){
        header("location:../notLoggedIn.php");
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks about right and was something like what I was expecting, however, it only works when I use one of the sessions. As in, if I remove the code for the registration session, I can login, but I can't login when the two sessions are in the if statement.

Comment: In which case i would suggest nesting the statements. Because we are using a logical OR only one of the conditions will be met.

If both conditions need to be met then you should use a logical AND

Second to that you could nest the statements if one depends on the other in this scenario.

i will edit my answer with both solutions :)

Comment: Will try again tomorrow. No time left today.

Comment: @tdrsam Great news i always use `isset()` for `$_SESSION` variables :)